# iPad Air 2 microphone not working since iOS 11 update

Tags: ios, ipad, microphone, voice-dictation

Is it a common problem for iPad Air 2 microphone to not work? My method of communication is dictation, so the microphone is critical. It works on my synced iPhone 6.

Comment: What indicates it's not working? What steps towards fixing this issue have you tried?

Comment: I tried every possible setting and preference in my disposal through iPhone I normally use.  I’m pretty good at  problem-solving  and I don’t know what happened. The iPad is never prompting for permission to use microphone.

Comment: Which application are you using to confirm the mic isn't working?

Comment: All of them. The only thing that allows dictation is Siri. Even that is a problem because it flips to Siri keyboard seemingly on its own.

Comment: BTW  thanks for answering. Didn’t expect such a quick response and petering out so may continue tomorrow.  No intention to ignore.

Comment: Problem solved! Tunneled deep into recesses of settings. Toggled potential culprit off/on, careful to tap DONE and SAVE  all the way back to Settings opening screen. Turned phone off/on. Must’ve fixed a glitch, as I did not change any settings. After reading a  settings comment on a settings conflict, a vague idea occurred to me.  Who knows with the glitch came from? Probably an iOS  came w one of the last 7 or so updates of Apple’s iOS. - not an unfounded statement if you read update details & experience the “said update’s” effects on your device.

Comment: Cool! Go ahead and add that as an answer!

Comment: BTW  I took screenshots as for visual clarity & will gladly post upon request.  Thought it best to avoid intimidatingly long “solution“  unless  requested.

Comment: Posting solutions is always good if you can!

Answer (score 1):

Backup the iPhone and then restore to factory. Then as you set up the iPhone restore the backup.

If the issue persists. Restore again and then dont restore the backup, set up the phone as is. If it works then your files have corrupted the audio. If it doesnt work, then it needs to be repaired. Take it to the Apple Store for repairs.

Comment: Thank you. I figured that was next but hated to admit it. Where do you suppose I’d  most likely pick up corrupt files?

Comment: I went ahead and posted the question on protecting my iPhone and iPad separately to avoid confusion.

Comment: Anything can be the culprit. More than likely its a stock OS issue. Backing up and restoring the backup will let you know if it persists.

Answer (score 0):

My iPad Pro's microphone recently stopped working almost completely – "almost" because you could still recognise loud sounds in a recording, but it was effectively unusable. The "Hey Siri" setup process wouldn't work etc.

The cause turned out to be mechanical: there was dirt stuck in the tiny microphone hole. I carefully dug it out with a needle and the microphone returned to its original performance.

The microphone's location depends on your iPad model. On my 9 inch Pro, it's a tiny (almost invisible) hole exactly in the middle of the top frame (the one with the power button).

Comment: Where’d you get the electron microscope ? lol